# Firebase Dynamic Links Marketing Campaign dynamic_link_first_open filter event by parameter

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I have created two Firebase Dynamic Links which has **utm_source=twitter** and **utm_source=facebook**.

After clicked the dynamic links, I able to see the **dynamic_link_first_open** events being logged, but the predefined audiences (**dynamic_link_first_open count > 0, source = facebook / source = twitter**) do not have any value (after one day).

Is this the correct way to filter the dynamic_link_first_open event by parameter?
Any steps I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

The audience result should show up when the number of users that satisfy the audience filter is more than 10. Otherwise, it will show that there are < 10.